# How to get live YouTube comments in Godot

Tags: c#, godot, gdscript

I am trying to make a chat interactive game on Godot. Twitch works really well, but YouTube isn't. I have read YouTube livestream API, but I don't really understand how I can use it, I tried to scrape comments with python, it worked, but it doesn't want to execute python file properly from Godot script. I also tried to find a way to do it in c#, because there is c# in Godot, but I don't really see any solutions online.

```
func _ready():
    var out = []
    OS.execute("/usr/local/bin/python3", ["/Users/viacheslavpopov/GodotProjects/TwitchYoutubeCIL/GetComments.py"], true, out)
    print(out[0])
```

That's what I tried with python, it only works when I don't include a library in python script, but it doesn't when there is any imported libraries.

I also tried to write some info in a .txt file in python script without importing anything, but it doesn't write anything in files when I execute .py file from Godot. Though it does when I start it from terminal.

Comment: Did you check the current path? It might be writing those txt somewhere else. Also, if python is a solution for you, try adding Python language support to Godot, there is an Addon in the asset library for that. I haven't use YouTube API, from Godot or otherwise, but it is an HTTP API, right? You could try using Godot's `HTTPRequest`.

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking exactly?